# NGRX: view not updating after state change

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a button that should open a google map. When I click it I can see the google scripts being inserted, which invokes a call back that sends a message to my reducer.

I see the message come and the logging shows that the value `1` is added to the state.

```
    case StateActions.SET_MAP_STATE:
        const tmp = { ...state, mapState: action.payload };
        console.log(tmp);
        return tmp;
```

my template looks like

```
<app-map
    *ngIf="(mapState | async) > 0"
></app-map>
```

and the component includes

```
    this.mapState = this.store.pipe(
        select(
            createSelector(
                getState,
                (state: AppState) => state.mapState
            )
        )
    );
```

Although the state clearly has changed, the map does not get added to my view. However, the next time I invoke an action somewhere on the screen, the map appears. Previously I had the map load at init time and never noticed the issue as lots of actions are firing then so the map always got loaded, but by chance now it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google map events are running outside of the angular zone changedetection, these are not so called 'monkey patched', like the standard `addEventListener`. I guess you are dispatching the event from within an event handler of a google map event. You should use `run` from the `NgZone`:

```
// event listener binded to a google map event
() => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // dispatch StateActions.SET_MAP_STATE action;
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why angular doesn't base its view changes on state changes, but adding the `ngZone.run` has at least fixed it. thanks

Comment: Because angular and ngrx are two different systems. Ngrx should then add the `ngZone.run` in their state change handler, which I assume will cause a slower system. All ngrx is doing, is making the state run in the same zone context as the function which called the dispatch. Probably for speed and consistency sake. If you want to abstract the google maps/zone layer, you can use the [angular-maps](https://angular-maps.com/) package